# How do I add XML data into an local XML file, so I can read it later

Tags: xml, apache-flex, air, adobe

I want to save XML data into a XML file.
So I can load it on the next startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AIR, you'll use the [File](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/File.html) and [FileStream](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) APIs to save files.  See more usage info [here.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Filesystem_11.html)

These aren't available to Flash Player.  You would probably use a server side solution or local shared objects ("Flash cookies").

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged it under FLEX.You can use the ActionScript API for file io handling.